# Mostrar u ocultar contenido con animacion de un <div> por clase y no a otros <div> con JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Mi problema es el siguiente: tengo un menu que contiene varias opciones () y quiero que al ubicar el cursor sobre algun div se despligue el contenido de dicho div, pero se despliega el contenido de los demas  padre.

Los  padre tienen una misma clase y los  dentro de esos  comparten otra clase.

**Codigo HTML:**

```
<button class="btn-plegable">
 <div class="submenu-gestor">
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="btn-plegable">
  <div class="submenu-gestor">
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </div>
</button>

(...)
```

**Codigo JavaScript/JQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(".btn-plegable").hover(function () {
       $(".submenu-gestor").stop().slideDown("slow");
    }, function(){
       $(".submenu-gestor").stop().slideUp("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion que encontre y resulta la mas optima es la siguiente:

```
<script>
    $(".btn-plegable").hover(function () {
       $(this).find(".submenu-gestor").stop(true, true).slideDown("slow");
    }, function(){
       $(this).find(".submenu-gestor").stop(true, true).slideUp("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Me faltaba apuntar al div sobre el que estaba con (this) y utilizar find para ubicar el  hijo y hacer la animacion estilo acordeón.

Tambien se hace de stop() para evitar formar colas; todo dentro de las mismas lineas del anterior .